# postgresql - Pagination/orderby with multiple tables' columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, pagination

Paging and sort by columns in 2 tables.

1. customer(id, first_name, last_name)
2. customer_email(customer_id, type, email).

One customer could have multiple emails.

Requirement: get 10 **customers** and sort by last_name, email.

```
--Sort by customer.last_name, customer_email.email

select c.*, ce.email
from customer c
inner join (select   distinct c.id, c.last_name
            from     customer c, customer_email ce 
            where    c.id = ce.customer_id 
            order by c.last_name, ce.email offset 0 limit 10
           ) AS paged_c on paged_c.id = c.id 
inner join customer_email ce on c.id = ce.customer_id
order by c.last_name, ce.email;
```

Doesn't work with the error

```
ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
LINE 6:                 order by c.last_name, ce.email offset 0 limi...
                                              ^
```

Comment: Describe what you are trying to do. It is not clear what output you are expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL is right to complain about your query; your requirements are unclear.

If you want the first 10 customers, ordered by last name an e-mail, but each customer can have several e-mail addresses, how do you do that? Which of the e-mail addresses is used for sorting the customers?

The error message basically reflects that uncertainty.

Come up with a clear definition of the sort order and translate that into SQL, then PostgreSQL will be happy to run your query.